# Grunt file: how can I add command line options at runtime? (Grunt 0.3.15+)

Tags: command-line-interface, command-line-arguments, gruntjs

How can I add and evaluate command line options within a Grunt file at runtime?

I've tried this:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  var cli = grunt.cli;

  cli.optlist["environment"] = {
    "short": "E",
    info: "Build environment",
    type: String
  };

  // This only outputs "environment=abc" if Grunt was called with
  //   --environment, with -E it returns "environment=undefined"
  console.log("environment=" + grunt.option("environment"));

  grunt.initConfig({ ... });

...
}
```

It works as long as I'm using the `--environment` switch, when using `-E`, `grunt.option()` returns undefined. Curiously the new option is shown in the `--help` screen.

Obviously the option object is only initialized once: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/0.3-stable/lib/grunt/cli.js#L105. I can't figure out why the new option is evaluated after all when using the long switch option.

I thought I should re-parse the options after adding a new option. I could invoke [grunt.tasks()](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/0.3-stable/lib/grunt/cli.js#L36) again, but this does not work, as I've expected.

Wrong way. Whats a better way?

Will I have the same limitations when creating a Grunt helper or task? Is it a general limitation which should be changed in Grunt internals?

This question is related to:

- Grunt 0.3.15+ (it should apply to 0.4.x too, as far as I can see)
- Node 0.6.18

### Edit

I've reverse engineered Grunt a bit more now and tried to change Grunt itself to allow myself to add options at runtime.

I skip writing the changes in Grunt as it's too much and misleading, I think. Let me describe the changes summarized.

This is my Grunt file so far:

```
grunt.addOptions({
    "environment": {
            "short": "L",
            info: "Build environment",
            type: String
    }
});
```

The `addOptions()` tried to add the passed options to the `optlist` object, then re-parsing the options object. Re-parsing was done just by wrapping [the code here](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/0.3-stable/lib/grunt/cli.js#L94) into a method  which is being called on initialization and at the endof `addOptions()`.

My implementation so far does not solve the problem. I would have to change too much in Grunt as the internal dependency structure of Grunt does not allow loading and parsing the Grunt file (which requires parsed command line options) and then initializing the command line option config further more (which was my approach).

Providing custom options for Grunt files should be discussed with the Grunt developers at GitHub, I think.

### My answer so far

So what would I answer...

My example above is correct and suitable as long as one can live with the long option.

I'll update this question as soon as I have more information. :)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe i'm missing something, but you need to test on both:

```
var environment = grunt.option("E") || grunt.option("environment");
```

Answer (score 0):

It is worth mentioning that as the amount of command line arguments you want to use grows, you *will* run into collisions with some arguments that grunt uses internally.

I got around this problem with [nopt-grunt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nopt-grunt)

From the Plugin author:

> Grunt is awesome. Grunt's support for using additional command line options is not awesome. The current documentation is misleading in that they give examples of using boolean flags and options with values, but they don't tell you that it only works that way with a single option. Try and use more than one option and things fall apart quickly.

*** I posted this before but I had such a bad time with command line arguments and this is ranked pretty high when you google "command line arguments in grunt" It's definitely worth checking out